# How to decompose storyboard views into XIBs

Tags: ios

Is it possible for me to extract views on my Storyboard into individual .xib files? I think that having a lot of views in a Storyboard makes it confusing and hard to view especially that I only code in a 13 inch screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Storyboards can be zoomed in and out, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do it in a automatic way, you would need to copy paste your views into Xibs. However you can instantiate the view controllers in the storyboard.

Something like this:

```
 UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                        @"Storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a basic perl script to extract Xib files from a Storyboard: http://pastebin.com/61wnRxSV

However it's not perfect, and probably needs some work - but may save you some time.

To run it, pass in the your Storyboard file as a command-line argument. It will save the .xib files in the current directory.

Each .xib file is named after the view controller it represents. Also, you'll want to load each Xib in Xcode - sometimes it says it fixed something in the file.

One issue seems to be the size of the view when viewed in Interface Builder, not sure what's up with that.

Hope this helps!